# What is the math to project a 3D object's center onto a 2D plane?

Tags: mathematics, rendering, geometry, coordinates, objective-c

What I really need is the x,y of the object when it is outside of the screen:

[image]

I'm actually coding a UI in Objective-C, not a game.

In this different kind of UI you navigate a 3D space with objects.

An observer is at (x=0,y=0,z=0) and objects have **realCenter** and **realSize**.

realSize is the size of the objects at z=1.

I have calculated the angular center of the objects to be:

```
angularCenterX = (objectRealCenter.x - observerCenterX) / distanceFromObserver
```

Objective-C code:

```
CGPoint angularCenter = CGPointMake((object.realCenter.x - observer.center.x) / distance,
                                    (object.realCenter.y - observer.center.y) / distance);
```

It works but when the observer passes the objects, the objects warp around. Instead of disappearing like they normally should, they come back.

The slider controls the z of the observer, as it moves and passes an object the objects comes back:

***I'm sorry the gif is too slow.***

[image]

Comment: Did you consider checking whether the object is in front of the view point, and skipping drawing it if not?

Comment: When the observer is in the center the equation is like this: realCenterX / distanceFromObserver. When the observe is very close to the object, the object is almost at its realCenterX, when the observer passes the object they are again very close and the object returns. I know for sure the equation I stumbled upon is definitely wrong.

Comment: No, this is pretty typical for projections. In games we manually cull items behind the camera, because otherwise they still project to valid on-screen positions (just mirrored, because we use a signed distance along the camera's forward vector for the division)

Comment: I NEED to know the center of the object behind the observer at all cost. The way animations work on the iPhone, you need to know the end location so you can animate to. If the start location and end location are in front of the observe the illusion that the object passes by will break. It works when I move a slider but it won't work with animations the way they are handled in UIKit.

Comment: Can you post an answer based on the answer in this post? I can't figure it out. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132469/how-can-i-calculate-the-center-of-an-object-relative-to-a-focal-point-and-a-movi

Comment: Take a look at this post again I added a picture which explains what I will need.

Comment: If the object is behind the observer, then it *does not have* a valid projection onto the plane. If you try to use a projection function, you will get a false projection that puts it in front of the observer, where the plane is. That is not what you want. What you can do instead is grab the position of the object *just before* it passes behind the observer, and animate to that distant position instead.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time trying to make projection functions work. I have thought of this but there's a problem. Suppose there are 5 objects at different positions in front of the observer and the observer passes by all of them in a single animation. If I use this method of animating all objects to a position just behind the observer it will look odd because some objects will cross a lot more distance than others. While the observer moves it will look like some objects are moving too instead of standing still.

Comment: You might have discovered the reason that games don't handle perspective projection via animation tweens.  We just have a game loop, and each frame we take the current position of the object relative to the camera and project that.

Comment: This will absolutely hammer the UIView animation system in iOS. Anyway, thanks again for your help. I might come back later with more questions.